# how to deploy and run multi language multi process app on heroku

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, heroku, web-applications

I want to build an app with potentially large number of io and computation heavy logic.

I learnt that one way to tackle this is to use node.js as a client facing service, then pass on client request to another backend service for heavy computing, then return the result asychronously.

This means I'll have at least two processes in my app: a node.js server and a backend service written in another language.

I also want to use heroku, but how do I deploy such an architecture to heroku? Do I have to confine all web and worker processes in the same box? For example, if I have 10 dynos, I want 2 of them run the node web server, the other 8 run my backend service as worker, how do I deploy such an architecture?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you really need multiple languages, you can use [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi).

Actually, both your Web dyno and your worker dynos could be node.js, if that works for you. In that case, you could use the exact setup described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36029289/1659476).

At any rate, you can separately configure as many Web and Worker dynos as you want with heroku ps:scale as described in [Heroku scaling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling). See also [What is a Heroku Dyno?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Heroku-Dyno/answer/Yoni-Rabinovitch)

Comment: Multi build pack looks good, however, it says: "The last buildpack in the list will be used to determine the process types for the application. Any process types defined from earlier buildpacks will be ignored", do you know what does this mean?

Comment: Hmmm, not quite sure what they mean by that. I suggest to post a question to their support, to ask them for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out MEAN stack. 
http://mean.io/#!/

**Mongo** (or any Database really, for heroku I recommend Postgres if you don't want a NoSQL database).

**Express** This is you backend that handles communications from you front-end to you database

**Angular** Super powerful front-end Single Page Application with a HUGE community and tons of add-ons and goodies.

**Node** The server that makes this all possible.

It's all written in javascript.

Heroku itself is a platform similar to an AWS Server that has node on it that allows you to run Express. You will build your apps then use the heroku command line to deploy your app to their servers after you have created your account. Heroku will also host your database via heroku add-ons.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Dynos will dynamically handle you processes as needed. Node isn't really run so much as a service as its running your backend (Express). Think of Node like Apache, it's what is running your server. Express is the backend running on that server and can run async so you can have as many processes running as you want, that's where the dynos will start to load balance for you.

Comment: I'm already using the mean stack, but I can't just use node for the backend, because I have some computation heavy logic, that's not a good use case for node. I need to hand over request from node/express to other service, probably via a messaging queue, hence my question

Comment: If you're using MEAN can you set up your other service as a REST call. That way on the front end you can use $http and $q and return a deferred promise while you wait for the external service to return the data.