# Heroku workers in dev

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm looking into using a `worker` as well as a `web` for the first time as I have to scrape a website. I'm just wondering before I commit to this about working in a dev environment. How do jobs in a queue get handled when I'm testing my app before it's pushed to Heroku?

I will probably be using RabbitMQ if that's relevant here.

Comment: What stack are you intending to use?

Comment: It's a Nodejs app with Express

Comment: Take a look at [How to setup dev environment for node.js with web and worker dynos on Heroku using RabbitMQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36029289/1659476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by testing.  You can unit test the code that does the scraping in isolation from any queue, and you can provide a mock implementation of the queue operations to handle a goodly portion of your integration tests.

I suppose you might want a real instance of the queue for certain tests, but depending on the nature of your project, you might be satisfied with the sorts of tests described in the first paragraph.

If you simply must test the queue operation and/or you want to run a complete copy of production locally then you'll  have to stand up an instance of Rabbitmq. You can stand one up locally or use one of the SAAS providers.

If you have multiple developers working on the project, you might want to make it easy for them by creating something like a vagrant script that sets up a complete environment in a vm. Or better still something like docker.  Doing so also gives you a lot more deployment options (making you less dependent on the heroku tooling).

Lastly, numerous CI solutions like [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#RabbitMQ) provide instances of popular services for running tests (including rabbit).